# What are the rules for Zombivors?

Tags: zombicide

A friend got some new survivors with Zombivors (zombified survivors) on the back side of their character card.  But there are no rules explaining how to play a Zombivor!  What are the rules for Zombivors?

- When does a survivor turn into a Zombivor?
- Which "side" does a Zombivor play for?
- Do they have free will?
- Do the Zombivor skills *replace* the survivor skills?  (Does XP start over from 0?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official rules for Zombivors are now available [here](http://guillotinegames.com/dl/po_rulebook_web.pdf).

Quick recap:

> Death and zombie infection can’t turn a real hero into a monster .
>   Your favorite Survivors can make it back to the game  as Zombie heroes
>   called Zombivors! When your Survivor is  eliminated by Zombies, you
>   can turn him into a Zombivor:  flip his Identity Card and savor a
>   bloody revenge . The Zombivors’ status is indicated with on the
>   Survivors’  Identity Card . All Survivor rules apply to them . The
>   killer feature about Zombivors is their incredible endurance: a
>   Zombivor is only eliminated by five Wounded  Cards in his Inventory
>   (instead of two for a standard  Survivor)
>
> Zombivors are great tanks . There’s a serious drawback, though
>   (besides the foul breath): at Yellow  Level, Zombivors don’t gain the
>   +1 Action Skill of  standard Survivors

It goes on to explain that you can either play with them starting as zombies, or play with them starting as normal but coming back as zombies if they are defeated (which obviously is a big advantage).

Comment: The [Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/coolminiornot/zombicide) for the original game came with six Zombivors.

Comment: "Does XP start over from 0?"

Comment: @David That sounds like something that should be asked as a separate question rather than in a comment.

Comment: @bwarner possibly.  I just noticed it in the original question and was wondering myself.